Is it possible to filter by multiple values at once?q
I have a dashboard that the use is to check the elegibility of HR candidantes to internal recruitment.
We have a lot of resume applications and that's why we created an automated analysis in Power BI. However, because we receive an average of 100 applications per recruitment, I want to be apple to check multiple IDs at once.
We have a Table Visual (https://i.sstatic.net/Qsz62tpn.png) that contains employee's information and some Columns are the analysis that tells us if the employee is able to participate or not (green or red icons and text).
Currently we use the ID segmentation icon (https://i.sstatic.net/iVW6bLPj.png) to filter one by one of the employees, but this takes too long because of the average of candidates.
Is it possible to use a segmentation that allows the user of the PBI to put multiple IDs at once and the Table Visual show only those IDs?
I didn't try anything, because I didn't find a visual that provides me what I want.

You can try Mass Filter visual in AppSource.
